# usage of range header in jsonrest for paging

Tags: json, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

new to DOJO..using JsonRest to get data from database...i have given range to display 0-1000 out of 50000 ...but it is displaying full data......requirement is that when that 1000 loaded  while scrolling the next request goes to server and rest of the data will display.... 
please help i tried a lot ......

my code

```
    myStore = dojo.store.Cache(dojo.store.JsonRest({
        target : "myip7080/GridExample/string"
    }), dojo.store.Memory());


    myStore.query({
        start: 0,
        count: 1000

      }).then(function(results){

          alert(results);             

      });


    grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
        store : dataStore = dojo.data.ObjectStore({
            objectStore : myStore
        }),
        structure : [ {
            name : "SNO",
            field : "sno",
            width : "100px",
            editable : true
        }, {
            name : "SNAME",
            field : "sname",
            width : "100px",
            editable : true
        }, {
            name : "SALARY",
            field : "salary",
            width : "200px",
            editable : true
        } ]
    }, "target-node-id"); // make sure you have a target HTML element with this id
    grid.startup();
    dojo.query("#save").onclick(function() {
        dataStore.save();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`dojo/store/Memory::query()` takes two parameters:

1. An object that queries the data
2. An [QueryOptions](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojo/store/api/Store.QueryOptions) object containing the options for this query (optional)

You can query specific entries from your data like this:

```
myStore.query(
    { name: "John Doe" }
); 
//returns all rows with name="John Doe"
```

You don't *have* to make a specific query. If you want all your data, just do `myStore.query("");`

If you want to limit the number of rows shown, you need to add a second parameter to represent your query options:

```
myStore.query(
    { name: "John Doe" }, 
    { start: 0, count: 1000 } //return 1000 results, starting at the beginning
);
```

See [the documentation for dojo/store/memory::query()](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojo/store/Memory#query).

Comment: @Desertly tanq for ur answer i tried that but requirement is that i need to load 1000 first thousand while i am scrolling i need to hit the database and get anther 1000......for this how can i know start and count in servlet from client as limit and offset to write the select query for the table.......plz answer this i am strugggling a lot

Comment: You're on the right track. Check out [JsonRestStore](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/data/JsonRestStore) ([API](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojox/data/JsonRestStore)) and/or an [OnDemandGrid](http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/tutorials/grids_and_stores/) for lazy loading. Give these a shot and update your question with your new code. It'll be easier to help if you try it yourself first. :)

Comment: Hello, I'm having the same problem and am failing to solve it from your instructions alone. Could you please give some more info? Where do I specify the count in the original questions code?